# How to insert the selected value in this form to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new developer in ASP.NET with C#. I developed an intranet web-based suggestion application which works as a pool for the suggestions submitted by the employees in my department.

I have the following database design:

```
Log Table: ID, Title, Description, DateSubmitted, Username, TypeID, StatusID
SuggestionsType Table: ID, Type
SuggestionsStatus Table: ID, Status
Employee Table: Username, Name, Title
```

I could be able to insert the suggestion with its title, datesubmitted, description and Username through the following code:

**ASP.NET Code**

```
<div ID="contactform">
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for="subject">
                        Type</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="155px" 
                                    Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#006666" AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
                                    DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true" OnDataBound="DropDownList_DataBound">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SafetySuggestionsType]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="text"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="dropdownlist" 
                            ErrorMessage="Please select a type for your suggestion or choose Others and put a type for it"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter a type for your suggestion"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="subject">
                        Subject</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" CssClass="text"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtSubject" 
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter a subject/title for your suggestion"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </li>

                    <%--The following hidden field is for inserting the date--%>
                    <li>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="dateSubmitted" runat="server" CssClass="text" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label for="message">
                        Your Suggestion</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSuggestion" runat="server" cols="50" CssClass="textarea" 
                            rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtSuggestion" ErrorMessage="Please enter your suggestion"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </li>
                    <li class="buttons">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imageField" runat="server" imageurl="images/Send.gif" 
                            OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                        <%--<input type="image" name="imageField" id="imageField" src="images/Send.gif" />--%>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
```

**C# Code:**

```
string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";
        string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Log (Title, DateSubmitted, Description, Username) values(@Title, @DateSubmitted, @Description, @Username)";
        string username = netID;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtSubject.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateSubmitted", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtSuggestion.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

What I need now is to insert the value of the selected type, **so how to do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more parameter for seletedType in your insert query:

```
string connString = "Data Source=dha00730-pmtq01\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO SafetySuggestionsLog (Title, DateSubmitted, Description, Username, TypeID) values(@Title, @DateSubmitted, @Description, @Username,@TypeID)";
        string username = netID;
        int typeID = Convert.ToInt64(DropDownList.SelectedValue);
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtSubject.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateSubmitted", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtSuggestion.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeID",typeID);    
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but **how to insert the TypeID?** and the Types will be displayed as a dropdownlist as shown in my ASP.NET code above.

Comment: do want to fill the dropdown list box with typeID ?

Comment: I am filling it with the Types from the SuggestionsType table. TypeID is a foreign key to the ID in the SuggestionsType table.

Comment: assign the DataText property of the dropdown with "Types" & DataValue property to "ID" `DropDownList.DataText = "Type"; DropDownList.DataValue = "ID";

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I just figured out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is same to what @Rohit Vyas mentioned in his solution but I just modified the following line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeID",typeID);
```

with the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeID",DropDownList.SelectedIndex);
```